# How do I make Cross Site Scripting from External Content work

Tags: api, cross-site

Currently using SP2013 on-prem and need to pull information from and in house application and display it on a page. Not using an iframe how can I pull specific information from a database and feed it into SharePoint. Is there a way to tell SharePoint to allow specific information to pass through? We want to keep this secure also. I'm a front end developer, so this isn't my specialty.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling information out of a database is going to require back-end code.

You have two options: A custom .NET web part or a custom web service you can query using JavaScript. If this in house application exposes its own web services this might be an option as well.

Anything more specific than that is going to require some knowledge of the external application and your infrastructure in general.

Comment: So, come to find out the information is coming straight from our database which is SQL Database. Are you aware of any 3rd party webparts I can grab from the internet or purchase?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this before but BCS - Business Connectivity Services - was created for just this scenario. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/business-connectivity-services-overview Have you looked into this?